# I have a gui program that I do not know what to do in the method mouseclick in order to make the program to work

Tags: java

This program does not work because I do not know the code for the method mouseClick. Could somebody help me with that.I am new, but new in java.

```
          import java.awt.*;
            import javax.swing.*;
          import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
           import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
          import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
            public class PracticeButton extends JFrame

          {
    JPanel pa;
    JButton bu;
    JLabel vi;
    JLabel fried;
    public PracticeButton()
    {
    super ("Practicing with Buttons");
    setLayout (new  FlowLayout());

    pa=new JPanel();
    add(pa);  //adding a panel


    ImageIcon ce= new ImageIcon ("ceviche.jpg");
    vi=new JLabel(ce);
    add(vi);


    bu= new JButton ("Click  Here to change the image");
    add(bu);  //adding a button


     fried = new JLabel ("friedcow.jpg");
    //cow=new JLabel(fried);
    //add(cow);


   MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
   bu.addMouseListener(handler);



}//end constructor

public class MouseHandler extends  MouseAdapter   // see  fig 14.21  page 581
{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event )

    {
if((event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1))

  {

    //I DO NOT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE.
    //I WANT THAT THE PICTURE CHANGES
    //WHEN I CLICK BUTTON bu.


   }

}
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseclick button you can make this :

```
newPicture = new ImageIcon("image/newPicture.png");
fried.setIcon(newPicture);
```

This will change the picture contain in **fried JLabel**. You can replace **fried** by another **JLabel** object.

If you have any question, you are welcome :)